# Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I am taking CryptoZombies Solidity tutorial and I have got such a problem:

```
Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable.
```

Here is the code:

```
function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        address payable _owner = address(uint160(owner()));
        _owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

I use VSCode and a Solidity extension. The IDE highlights this line in red:

```
address payable _owner = address(uint160(owner()));
```

and displays the above error. What should I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `payable()` typecast function to change the type of an `address` to `address payable`.

```
// assuming `owner()` returns an `address`
// it's redundant to convert it to `uint160` and then back to `address`
address payable _owner = payable(owner());
```